# AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: python, arcgis-10.2, spatial-analyst

I am trying to use a conditional statement to generate a raster with binary values from a raster with probability values (floating point raster).  This is easily done within ArcMap by batching the process, but I need to do it >300 times with a different 'threshold' value each time.

Here is my code:

```
# Import arcpy module
    import arcpy

# Import environment and spatial analyst modules
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Set Workspace for Rasters 
    env.workspace = "C:\May_2014\python_example.gdb"
    Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")

# Local Variables
    MyTable = "table_for_python"

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (MyTable, ["threshold"]) as mycursor:
        counter = 0
        for row in mycursor:
            raster = Rasters[counter]
            outCon = Con(raster >= mycursor, 1,0)
            outCon.save("C:\May_2014\python_example_2.gdb\Con_" + raster)
            counter = counter + 1
```

I keep getting the following error message after the line:

```
outCon.save('Con_' + raster)
```

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'save'.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: it looks like your `outCon` variable is getting assigned an integer value rather than a raster.  try adding a `print outCon` statement between `outCon =` and `outCon.save` to make sure `outCon` is getting assigned a raster value as it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take it counter is for the output, the first threshold is 0, the next is 1 and so on for each row in the table.

```
# Import arcpy module
    import arcpy

# Import environment and spatial analyst modules
    from arcpy import env
    from arcpy.sa import *
    arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")

# Set Workspace for Rasters 
    env.workspace = "C:\May_2014\python_example.gdb"
    Rasters = arcpy.ListRasters("*", "All")

# Local Variables
    MyTable = "table_for_python"

    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor (MyTable, ["threshold"]) as mycursor:
        counter = 0
        for ThisRaster in Rasters:
          for row in mycursor:
              # ThisRaster is a string, make it a raster by Raster(ThisRaster)
              outCon = Con((Raster(ThisRaster) >= float(row[0])), 1,0)
              outCon.save("C:\May_2014\python_example_2.gdb\Con_" + raster + str(counter))
              counter = counter + 1
```

Your iteration was a bit funny, the pythonic way is to `for var in list:`

Comment: Thanks, Michael.  I have tried running it using this new code, but I still get the same error message.  I really appreciate your help.  I am a Python rookie.

Comment: It's nothing to do with the counter, it's the `Con` function returning a int for some reason. Do a `type(outCon)` to see what the return type is.

Comment: for some reason the con function isn't recognizing ThisRaster as a raster, rather as a string. Using Raster(ThisRaster) will make it into a raster object. That should work.

Comment: [The docs for .ListRasters](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v0000001s000000) say it returns a list of strings, not rasters.  That, after all, is why evaluating an expression like `"C:\May...\Con_" + raster` could even succeed in the OP's code. (Incidentally, `Con` is superfluous: the inequality will return a 0-1 grid.) However, although I think you have identified the fundamental problem, your code obviously won't work: you haven't initialized `raster`!

Comment: Isn't that what Raster(ThisRaster) does? I've seen this syntax used to initialize a raster at the time of the Con in examples. I agree that the Con is superfluous, but it allows the op to change values 0,1 to 255,1 at a whim.

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for your responses.  I really appreciate your help.  It's working for me now, with the following additional changes: 1) outCon = Con(raster >= mycursor[0], 1,0) instead of  outCon = Con((ThisRaster >= row[0]), 1,0) and 2) needed to save the new rasters in the same file geodatabase.  Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into a similar problem and used the idea here to tell Python that my layers are rasters using Raster(). However, I did this not in the Con() function itself, but rather before that, when specifying the in_conditional raster, in_true_raster and in_false raster. E.g.,

```
inRaster1 = Raster("mydata1")
inRaster2 = Raster("mydata2")

outCon = Con((inRaster1 == 3) & (inRaster2 < 5), inRaster1, 6)
```